# low-level call failed

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm using the crowdsale contract (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol). I have deployed a detailedERC20 smart contract. When I send the ether to the crowdsale contract it shows me the following error:
SafeERC20: low-level call failed

When I use transfer() externally it works fine.

computer Environment
Ganache-cli

Comment: From what I see that error message is coming from 'SafeErc20.sol' (https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol) . When calling the fallback function (ie. sending ether to the contract) it'll pass through the "callOptionalReturn" function of this contract, where it fails for some reasons . Would it be possible for you to post your contract so I can have a look at it ?

Comment: It's the crowdsale contract https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol

Comment: the ERC20 contract is also openzeppelin ERC20 contract: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol

Comment: @AyushKaul How do you make the transfer to the crowdsale contract? ie from javascript or solidity.

Comment: @Ismael I'm using metamask to send ether to the crowdsale contract address. Javascript (web3) can also be used.

Comment: @AyushKaul It is difficult to determine your problem because we have nothing to examine. I've used OpenZeppelin and MetaMask to create crowdsales and tokens and I've transfered tokens without issue so they work as expected and are not the problem. General rules are if you use `transferFrom` perhap you have to call `approve` before, make sure you or the contracts have enough token balance, ensure the `decimals` are set correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Potential areas to look at which could be causing your problem when using the default emission Crowdsale:

- Set an appropriate rate
- Need to transfer (enough) tokens to the Crowdsale

For information on the rate: https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/crowdsales#crowdsale-rate

> Understanding the rate of a crowdsale is super important, and mistakes here are a common source of bugs.
>
> ✨ HOLD UP FAM THIS IS IMPORTANT ✨
>
> Firstly, all currency math is done in the smallest unit of that currency and converted to the correct decimal places when displaying the currency.

For information on default emission: https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/crowdsales#default-emission

> In the default scenario, your crowdsale must own the tokens that are sold.

I recommend reading through the OpenZeppelin documentation on Crowdsales:
https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/crowdsales

If you have more questions about OpenZeppelin you can always ask in the [community forum](https://forum.zeppelin.solutions)

Comment: I think the problem is that crowdsale smart contract doesn't have enough tokens. Hence transfer is reverted.

Answer (score 0):

The crowdsale token balance is lower, And you need to consider the value that you're passing as the smallest unit which is **wei**.

*this is not working*

```
var amount = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether');
await this.crowdsale.buyTokens(accounts[1], { value: amount });
```

*this works*

```
var amount = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'wei');

await this.crowdsale.buyTokens(accounts[1], { value: amount });
```